# Should all dict params in python decorated by asterisks

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def accept(**kwargs):
    pass
```

If I defined `accept` and I expect it be called by passing a param which is dict.  Are the asterisks necessary for all dict params?

What if I do things like:

```
def accept(dict):
    pass

dict = {...}
accept(dict)
```

Specifically speaking, I would like to implement a `update` method for a class, which keeps a dict as a container. Just like the dict.update method, it takes a dict as a param and modify the content of the container. In this specific case should I use the kwargs or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `f` below. The function `f` has two parameters, a positional one called `name` and a keyword argument `message`. They are local variable in the frame of the function call.

When you do `f("John", **{"foo": "123", "message": "Hello World"})`, the function `f` will **unpack** the dictionary into local variable by its key/value pair. In the end you have three local varaibles:  `name`, `foo=123`, and `message=Hello World`.

---

The purpose of `**kwargs`, double asterisks is for uknown keyword arguments.

Contrast this:

```
def f(name, message=None):
    if message:
        return name + message
    return name
```

Here I am telling user if you ever want to call `f`, you can pass a keyword argument `message`. This is the only kwarg I will ever accept and expect to receive if there is such one. If you try `f("John", foo="Hello world")` you will get unexpected keyword argument.

`**kwargs` is useful if you don't know ahead of time what keyword arguments you want to receive (very common for dispatching to lower-level functions/methods), then you use it.

```
def f(name, message=None, **kwargs):
    if message:
        return name + message
    return name
```

In the second example, you can do `f("John", **{"foo": "Hello Foo"})` while omitting `message`. You can also do `f("John", **{"foo": "Hello Foo", "message": "Hello Message"})`.

1. Can I ignore it?

As you see yes you can ignore it. Here `f("John", **{"foo": "Hello Foo", "message": "Hello Message"})` I still only use `message` and ignore everything else.

Don't use `**kwargs` unless you need to be careless about the inputs.

1. What if my input is a dictionary?

If your function simply takes the dictionary and modifies the dictionary, NOT using individaul key, then just pass the dictionary. There is no reason to make a dictionary item into variables.

But here are two main usages of `**kwargs`.

Supposed I have a class and I want to create attributes on the fly. I can use `setattr` to set class attributes from input.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(**kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

If I do `Foo(**{"a": 1, "b": 2})` I will get `Foo.a` and `Foo.b` at the end.

This is particularly useful when you have to deal with legacy code. However, there is a big security concern. Imagine you own a MongoDB instance and this is a container for writing into a database. Imagine this dict is a request form object from user. The user can shovel ANYTHING and you simply save it in the database like that? That's a security hole. Make sure you validate (use a loop).

The second common usage of kwargs is that you don't know things ahead of times which I have covered (it's actually sort of the first common usage anyway).

Comment: Yeah, but if I do know that the param will definitely be one dict. Can I ignore it?

Comment: Yes. See my answer or provide extra context.

Comment: I re-read your comment, you are expecting the input to be a dict? I suggest no then. But read my updated post.

Comment: I would like to implement a `update` method for a class, which keeps a dict as a container. Just like the dict.update method, it takes a dict as a param and modify the content of the container. In this specific case should I use the kwargs or not?

Comment: Just pass the dictionary. I assume something like this ``self.container = new_dict_i_passed_in`` where ``new_dict_i_passed_in`` comes from ``update(self, new_dict_i_passed_in)``. When you do ``**``, inside the function call, you are unpacking key/value of the dictionary into individual local variable.

Comment: Yeah, but not assignmen, for the existent key I update it with the new value, for non-existent key I add it. Same behavior like self._container[key] = dict[key].

Comment: @zoujyjs yes. you can just do an update using a loop. That's safer than overrideing the entire container. Just use a loop.

Answer (score 2):

`**` in function parameter collects all keyword arguments as a dictionary.

```
>>> def accept(**kwargs): # isinstance(kwargs, dict) == True
...     pass
...
```

Call using keyword arguments:

```
>>> accept(a=1, b=2)
```

Call using `**` operator:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> accept(**d)
>>> accept(d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: accept() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)
```

See [Python tutorial - Keyword argument](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) and [Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

BTW, don't use [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict) as variable name. It shadows builtin function/type [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict).

Comment: What if I ignore the `**`, I can read the param correctly either. As for the example above I print the key val pair of the dict.

Comment: @zoujyjs, Sorry, but I don't understand the comment.

Comment: See my updates, I mean that without this double asterisks the function works well.

Comment: @zoujyjs, Do you mean the second function (`def accept(dict): ...`) works when given single dictionary argument?

Comment: Yeah, exactly, I print the key, value pair.

Comment: @zoujyjs, Use the first form if you want to call the function with keyword arguments: `accept(a=1, b=2)`. Use the second form if you want to pass a dictinoary: `accept({'a': 1, 'b': 2})`

Comment: @zoujyjs, Yes. It depends on the use case of the function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a dictionary as input to a function, you can simply do it like this

```
def my_function1(input_dict):
    print input_dict

d = {"Month": 1, "Year": 2}

my_function1(d)     # {'Month': 1, 'Year': 2}
```

This is straight forward. Lets see the `**kwargs` method. `kwargs` stands for keyword arguments. So, you need to actually pass the parameters as key-value pairs, like this

```
def my_function2(**kwargs):
    print kwargs

my_function2(Month = 1, Year = 2)
```

But if you have a dictionary and if you want to pass that as a parameter to `my_function2`, it can be done with unpacking, like this

```
my_function2(**d)
```